# PHP ODBC error: tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes

Tags: php, odbc, out-of-memory

I've Been trying to make this work for a whole day and think I need help. I have read/tried a lot of related posts here but nothing seems to solve the problem.

I'm getting this error:

`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 524288) (tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sandbox\odbc.php on line 26`

when executing the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$res = odbc_exec($connection, $query); 
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res) )
{ 
   print_r($row); 
}
```

The "line 26" referred to by the error message is this line.

```
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res) )
```

Other info:
Running PHP version 5.3.24 on IIS 7, Windows Server 2008;
PHP memory_limit: 500M (have come to increase this insanely high after lower numbers didn't work)

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to fetch from the DB that'd require trying to allocate 4gig of ram? Any blob fields in there?

Comment: It could be that PHP.ini is restricting the amount of data processed at one time.

Comment: maybe do ini_get('memory_limit'); to be shure that you have really 500M (524288 are only 512K)

Comment: @MarcB it was a table having just 156 rows, no blob in it. Btw, the target db is MS SQL. Thanks!

Comment: @steven yes just tried that, also phpinfo says memory_limit is 5000M. thanks

Comment: @Phil If that wasn't a typo, that might be your problem. It might be trying to allocate 5000M, while your server may not have this amount of ram.

Comment: @gdscei it was originally set to 128MB and I was getting the same error message back then -> "Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2621440) (tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes)". thanks

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this exact same error and it turned out that the table I was selecting from had a field of type nvarchar(max). Reducing the length of the field (to nvarchar(100), for example) resolved the issue for me.